# Show div on hover : div didn't show on hover

Tags: css, hover

I have this code :

```
#banner {-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 100px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 100px; -moz-border-radius-topleft: 100px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 100px; border-top-left-radius: 100px; border-top-right-radius: 100px; position:relative;}
#submenu { color: #fff; margin: 0 2%; position: relative; bottom: -0px; text-align: center; font-family: Oswald; font-weight: 700; font-size: 15px; padding:3px; z-index:1; visibility:hidden; opacity:0; -webkit-transition:300ms; -moz-transition:300ms; -o-transition:300ms; transition:300ms; }
#banner:hover #submenu { visibility:visible; opacity:1; }
```

And when I hover the `#banner` ID, the `#submenu` won't show. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : Here's the HTML code, if necessary :

```
<div id="banner"><div id="submenu">foo</div></div>
```

Comment: Works fine.  However, on a JSFiddle I had to take off the `color: #fff` on the `#submenu`.  The text was showing up white on a white background so it just looked invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/4mcz0axk/
Div is showing up but the text of the color is white so it might not be visible.
In the fiddle shared, I intentionally changed it to black and it is working perfectly fine.

```
#banner {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 100px;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
#submenu {
    color: black;
    margin: 0 2%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 3px;
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 300ms;
    -moz-transition: 300ms;
    -o-transition: 300ms;
    transition: 300ms;
}
#banner:hover #submenu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```